# Powershell in SQLCLR?

Tags: powershell, sqlclr

In the past I've been able to embed a sripting languate (like JScript) inside the SQLCLR, so scripts can be passed as parameters of functions, to perform certain calculations. Here is a simplistic example (the function ssScriptExecute returns a concatenation of all the print's in the script):

```
select dbo.ssScriptExecute( 'print("Calculation: "+(1+2/3) );' )

-- Calculation: 1.6666666666666665
```

I'd love to be able to embed a Powershell runtime in the same way. But I've had all sort of problems because the runtime tries to find assemblies by path, and there are no paths inside the SQlCLR. I'm happy to provide more information on the errors I get, but I was wondering if anybody has tried this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use il code injection to modified System.Automation.Management.
make variable version in GetPSVersionTable() be "2.0"
then i can run Powershell Code in SQL Server.

Be sure reference this modified dll in your visual studio project.

http://www.box.net/shared/57122v6erv9ss3aopq7p

btw, automated registering all dll you needed with running powershell in SQL

you can use this ps1 code

http://www.box.net/shared/tdlpu1875clsu8azxq4b

Comment: PSHost host = new PoShSQL.PoShSQLHost();
RunspaceConfiguration config = new PoShSQL.PoShSQLConfig();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, config);

Comment: Seriously?... that'd be fantastic! I'll check that I can make this work soon. Thanks. +1 for the hack.

Comment: but... you need to new a configuration yourself... or even "get-date" cant be used ><

Comment: How did u modify System.Management.Automation.dll if I may ask.

Comment: inject il code and resign it with strong name use another key file, so... it's probably not compatible with native Microsoft.PowerShell series dlls... orz

Comment: Do you mind uploading the source code? I'm not comfortable adding a binary into my database without checking the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this is to create a WCF service hosting powershell, and let SQLCLR send the request dbo.ssScriptExecute(...) to that service for execution.
Besides from that, I've also successfully embedded paxScript.net in the SQLCLR (an interpreter that does not have the memory leak problems of the DLR languages).

Answer (score 0):

I thought SQLCLR was restricted to just a certain set of assemblies and PS Automation is not one of them.

Comment: That's correct. But restricted only means not supported. You can still register assembies not in their approved list.

Comment: Ahh, that didn't occur to me. I looked into creating a PowerShell CLR, noticed System.Management.Automation wasn't one of the blessed assemblies and stopped. It would be interesting if you could get it working.

Comment: one problem I found in embedding JScript (or any DLR based scripting language) is that there is no way to unload the temporary assembly created from the script... this is a leak (every time you run the ssScriptExecute a new assembly gets loaded into memory, and it remains there).. uff